# Problemas al tomar las variables con REQUEST Y POST

Tags: php, post

Estoy intentando utilizar una variable que he traido con `$_REQUEST[]` y luego en una condición donde digo que si el metodo fue POST, ejecuto una consulta en la que utilizo esa variable pero no me la toma correctamente.

Éste es el codigo, la variable que necesito utilizar es `$fad_id` y poder utilizarla en la consulta:

```
$fad_id = $_REQUEST['fad_id']; <br>
$modo = $_REQUEST['modo'];

if ($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == "POST")
{   
    $sql = "SELECT fat_id FROM fat_mstr WHERE fad_id = $fad_id";
    $db->ejecutar($sql);

    while ($val=$db->traer_datos_num()) {
        $fat_id=$val[0];
    }

    var_dump($fat_id);
?>
```

Comment: No te lanza ningun warning??, `$_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == "POST"` debería ser: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"` debes poner comillas para llamar un elemento del arreglo por su clave. Si en el formulario html envías los datos mediante POST, usa $_POST[].

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta ya lo pude solucionar de otra forma

Comment: @ManuelMosquera, podrías compartir la solución con el resto de usuarios?

Answer (score 1):

Te has olvidado las comillas en la variable $_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar era algo el error venia de otra parte muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

quisiste decir

```
  $fad_id = $_REQUEST['fad_id']; <br>
  $modo = $_REQUEST['modo'];

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {   
      $sql = "SELECT fat_id FROM fat_mstr WHERE fad_id = $fad_id";
      $db->ejecutar($sql);

      while ($val=$db->traer_datos_num()) {
          $fat_id=$val[0];
      }

      var_dump($fat_id);
  ?>
```

Comment: Hola podrías explicar un poco mas tu respuesta?, así le sirve a todo el mundo no solo al que hizo la pregunta.